# List index find by given string

Tags: python, list

I have a list and I have a given string. The list looks like the following:

`["hello, whats up?", "my name is...", "goodbye"]`

I want to find the index in the list of where the given string is, for example:

- If the given string is "whats" I want it to return 0
- If the given string is "name" it'll be returning 1

I tried to use `list_name.index(given_string)` but it says "whats" is not in the list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the index of an item in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-in-a-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because `whats` is not really present in the list. The list actually has `"hello, whats up?"`. So if you set the value of given_string to be like - `given_string = "hello, whats up?"`, then you will get 0 as index. The index method just compares the values, in this case entire string. It does not check for values within the string.

Edit 1:
This is how I would do it:

```
list = ["hello, whats up?", "my name is...", "goodbye"]
for index, string in enumerate(list):
     if 'whats' in string:
             print index
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the follwoing:

```
l = ["hello, whats up?", "my name is...", "goodbye"]
sub_s = "name"
indx = [i for i, s in enumerate(l) if sub_s in s]
print(indx) # [1]
```

This is more robust in the case where you have more then 1 index